# Regex - get list comma separated allow spaces before / after the comma

Tags: regex, parsing, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I try to extract an images array/list from a commit message:

```
String commitMsg = "#build #images = image-a, image-b,image_c, imaged , image-e #setup=my-setup fixing issue with px"
```

I want to get a list that contains:

```
["image-a", "image-b", "image_c", "imaged", "image-e"]
```

NOTES:

A) should allow a **single** space before/after the comma (,)

B) ensure that `#images =`  exists but exclude it from the group

C) I also searching for other parameters like #build and #setup so I need to ignore them when looking for #images

What I have until now is:

```
/(?i)#images\s?=\s?<HERE IS THE MISSING LOGIC>/
```

I use find() method:

```
def matcher = commitMsg =~ /(?i)#images\s?=\s?([^,]+)/ 

if(matcher.find()){
    println(matcher[0][1])
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's Groovy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?i)(?:\G(?!^)\s?,\s?|#images\s?=\s?)(\w+(?:-\w+)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lm12tI/1). *Details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive mode on
- `(?:\G(?!^)\s?,\s?|#images\s?=\s?)` - either the end of the previous regex match and a comma enclosed with single optional whitespaces on both ends, or `#images` string and a `=` char enclosed with single optional whitespaces on both ends
- `(\w+(?:-\w+)*)` - Group 1: one or more word chars followed with zero or more repetitions of `-` and one or more word chars.

See a [Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/PwkO4F):

```
String commitMsg = "#build #images = image-a, image-b,image_c, imaged , image-e #setup=my-setup fixing issue with px"
def re = /(?i)(?:\G(?!^)\s?,\s?|#images\s?=\s?)(\w+(?:-\w+)*)/
def res = (commitMsg =~ re).collect { it[1] }
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[image-a, image-b, image_c, imaged, image-e]
```

An [alternative Groovy code](https://ideone.com/ZZuOL2):

```
String commitMsg = "#build #images = image-a, image-b,image_c, imaged , image-e #setup=my-setup fixing issue with px"
def re = /(?i)(?:\G(?!^)\s?,\s?|#images\s?=\s?)(\w+(?:-\w+)*)/
def matcher = (commitMsg =~ re).collect()
for(m in matcher) {
    println(m[1])
}
```